# JQuery: Each function stopping the parent function running

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a password reset form I am validating two password inputs (password & password2) to ensure they match against a regex, are of a certain length and match one another. Any problems highlights the offending input and throws up an error message.

To check both inputs against a regex and for length I am using an 'each' function but it doesn't work. In fact when it's in there the whole checkform() function doesn't appear to run (I tested it with the alert box - when I remove the each function the alert shows, when its in there, it doesn't).

Here's the script:

```
  function checkform(){

alert("function running");
regex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;    

//This each function stops checkform() from running //

$("#password, #password2").each(function() {
    if($(this).val().length>5){
        $(this).css('border', '');
    } else {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        $("#errormsg").html("Oops! Please enter a valid password");
        return false;           
    }
}
//End of problem code

if($("#password").val() != $("#password2").val()){
    $("#password").css('border', '1px solid red');
    $("#password").css('border', '1px solid red');
    $("#errormsg").html("Oops! Your passwords don't match");
    return false;
    } else {
        $("#errormsg").empty();
    }
   return true;
   }
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: Missing ")" `})
//End of problem code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code

```
function checkform(){

    alert("function running");
    regex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;    

    //This each function stops checkform() from running //

    $("#password, #password2").each(function() {
        if($(this).val().length>5){
            $(this).css('border', '');
        } else {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
            $("#errormsg").html("Oops! Please enter a valid password");
            return false;           
        }
    }); // <-- close the "(" of the each function
    //End of problem code

    if($("#password").val() != $("#password2").val()){
        $("#password").css('border', '1px solid red');
        $("#password").css('border', '1px solid red');
        $("#errormsg").html("Oops! Your passwords don't match");
        return false;
        } else {
            $("#errormsg").empty();
        }
       return true;
       }
```

Comment: Great - thanks for your help. Getting to grips with JQuery so this is a big lesson learnt.